# How to retrieve page HTML from Lighthouse?

Tags: lighthouse

I'm trying to add some custom metrics to Lighthouse. In order to do some basic checks, I need to get the raw HTML of the webpage.

I've tried without any success using `driver.sendCommand` (`DOM.getDocument` or `DOM.getFlattenedDocument`) and `driver.querySelectorAll('html')` and `driver.evaluateAsync('document.documentElement.outerHTML')`.
How can I manage to get the raw HTML from Chrome into Lighthouse?

Thank you,

Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a straightforward call to `driver.evaluateAsync` from withing a gatherer.  Something like:

```
const expression = `document.querySelector('html').outerHTML`;
const html = await passContext.driver.evaluateAsync(expression);
```

Inside of the `afterPass` of a gatherer should be able to get the html.  [HTML w/o Javascript](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/gather/gatherers/html-without-javascript.js) does this.  Modify the expression in that gatherer to get the idea of how it should work.

Here's a really rough example of just logging the html once it's gathered from hacking on HTML w/o Javascript:

[image: Rough Screenshot]